# I have installed textblob and it works when I import it separately on py interpretor but what I run program it gives module not found error

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have installed textblob by pip install and it works when I import it separately on py interpretor but when I run program on VS code it gives module not found error

Comment: The provided information is not sufficient to answer the question. It may be a problem with the python interpreter that you are using for VS Code, the module might be installed on some different python instance.

Answer (score 0):

check the interpreter if you are using venv or anaconda or whatever

[image]

just click on python